# What positive changes will NVIDIA support to Linux release?

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

I've recently heard about NVIDIA is joining the Linux Foundation. I just tought, well here comes full functioning NVIDIA Drivers. My card is a G210M, and I have graphic acceleration, glxgears echoes 2400 fps. GTK benchamark doesnt go that well (GTKPerf show slow results). Everithing is fine, but I cant switch to virtual terminals.

With nouveau  i have a little graphic acceleration with glxgear throwing 1100 fps, but the virtual terminal works.

I' ll never understand, why Nvidia doest release a full linux functioning driver. Will this joining to the linux foundation resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. It's probably just for marketing - full accelerated drivers will never be released by nvidia; they always claim there is too much of their own and foreign "intellectual property" in them.

Comment: Cant the just provide it in binary?